# Django Admin Page not found (404), urls.py + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Going to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin` returns this error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in the_food_blog.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='home']
<slug:slug>/ [name='post_detail']
^(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, admin, matched the last one.
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
]
```

Removing `+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` fixes this but why?

Comment: Looks like your blog urls are interrupting your project urls. Might need to see your media urls on settings to figure out why

Answer (score 0):

You can use these:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I hope to solve your problem!